# Why Inline CSS is taking precedence over my custom CSS stylesheet when I am using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to add some of the css properties like changing the background of my website.

Have a look at my my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-light mt-4">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="brandname" href="#">Mohit Tembhurkar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-4" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-4" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-4" href="#">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-4" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" id="hireme">Hire Me</button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container" id="hcon" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            column 1
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            column 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            column 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my CSS stylesheet, if I try to change the background color of body, it won't change. Also, I want margins around the container div, which is not implementing with CSS.

```
body {
 background-color: #fdf0d5;;
}

#hcon {
 margin: 150px;
}
```

So, I am forced to write inline CSS which finally solves this issue:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?           family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?  family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #fdf0d5;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-light mt-4">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="brandname" href="#">Mohit Tembhurkar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-4" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-4" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-4" href="#">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-4" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" id="hireme">Hire Me</button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container" style:'margin: 150px;' >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            column 1
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            column 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            column 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I wish to style everything in CSS stylesheet. How would it be possible. Can anyone please help me?

But I wish to style everything in CSS stylesheet. But the Inline CSS is taking precendence whenever I am using Bootstrap. How do I solve this?

Comment: Inline CSS always take precedence because it's loaded last.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to find a way to get precedence over the Bootstrap styles using your own stylesheet. CSS is evaluated in terms of [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).
There are some recommendations in this about how to override a third party library, but its also worth mentioning that whichever CSS file gets loaded last breaks specificity ties. So a quick modification you could make is changing:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
...
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

to

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Now to change background color, we need to override the specificity of the third party library, Bootstrap:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);
  font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--bs-body-font-weight);
  line-height: var(--bs-body-line-height);
  color: var(--bs-body-color);
  text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align);
  background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

(this is taken from the unminified CDN https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.css)

So now that we've re-ordered our loading order, we can actually just use the *same specificity* as Bootstrap with the `body` selector:

```css
body {
  background-color:fdf0d5
}
```

For further cases where you wish to override bootstrap you can use your browsers devtools to check the classes of each element in order to determine a more specific style so CSS prioritizes your custom styles.